# I get a 404 error when making a Fetch Get Request

Tags: javascript, get, fetch-api

I am trying to get some weather info from a weather api. When I load this fetch code in Chrome's console I get a 404 error.

```
const getWeather = () => {
  return fetch('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
q=London&appid=' + apiKey)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(weather => console.log(JSON.stringify(weather)))
}

getWeather();
```

It also shows this, "http://127.0.0.1:5500/" before the url I'm trying to fetch. What could be causing this to be added and how do I get this fetch request to run properly? I would love any assistance anyone can provide.

Comment: Maybe add `http://` to the url?

Comment: Is your API key valid?

Comment: It was the "http://" thing. I just copied the url from Open Weather Map and didn't think a thing about the http not being there. Thank you Mark!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url that you use is considered as a relative url (so the browser prepends it with your site's current location). To make it absolute url, you could either use

`'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=' + apiKey`

or

`'//api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=' + apiKey`

the last one is to use the same protocol as your site runs on.

Learn more: [Absolute URLs vs relative URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#Absolute_URLs_vs_relative_URLs)